# What's the best database design for implementing categories and tags?

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

For example, a news website might have "categories" such as Politics, Business, Entertainment, Sports, Lifestyle, Tech, Science, Health, ... etc. Each article belongs to only one category, but can have multiple "tags". Tags are just like hashtags we see on social media and can be very detailed.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450263/what-the-best-way-to-add-multiple-tags-to-a-blog-post) shows the best approach to design a database for "tags". What if I need to add "categories"?

I'm not sure if it's okay to simply record each article's category in its table row. Maybe adding a column named "Category"? If so, is the performance still good when visitors want to search, say, all articles which belong to "Business" category and have "Facebook" tag?

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm)! Have a `post` table with a specific given category (main topic). Then have a `tag` table with every possible subject. Then have a `post_tag` [joining table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) with `post_pk` and `tag_id` as fields! I'll write this up as an answer if you find it helpful!

Comment: @Vérace Thanks. I didn't find the answer in that website. But I guess your suggestion matches with my speculation. That is, using three tables: `posts`, `tags`, and `posts_tags`, and placing the category information in the `posts` table (in the `Category` column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each article has at most one (or one and only one) category, then you would include the category information in the `article` table.

I would *not* include the text name of the category in the table. I would have a separate `category` table with the category name and an integer ID value. As there are presumably a relatively small number of possible categories, this shouldn't have a major impact on performance; and it would prove its value the first time someone had you change the name of a category.

You'll also probably want an index on `article.category_id`, if searches by tag and category will be very common (as I imagine they would be).

Comment: Thanks. Will performance be impacted if category names are stored directly in the `article` table? Usually, category names like Politics, Business, Entertainment, Sports, ... etc would hardly be changed.

Comment: There'll be more disk space required for the table (you're storing the full name multiple times, rather than an integer value). Query times might be a fraction of a millisecond faster (nothing noticeable); or might in fact be a fraction slower (because they have to read in that text value from every row). Changes might be rare, but would touch a significant percentage of the rows when they did happen, and could take a while to process (vs no noticeable time to update the row I the lookup table). My rule is values that are user-meaningful should not be used as keys, because they will change.

Answer (score 0):

1. Design the `SELECTs`.
2. Try them out.
3. Try them out with a *large* dataset.
4. Get rid of `AND deleted = 1` -- it is a performance killer!  But how?

OK, I have done all that for you.  See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists).

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I understand you, but that doesn't seem to talk about both category and tags.

Comment: A 'category' is just another name for a 'tag'.  Sure, a article has only one "category", but the Lists table works just fine with that, too.